# Total space of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$ over $\mathbb{P}^n$ 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

It is well known that total space of the tautological line bundle $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ over projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ is closed subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$. My question is how to realize total space of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ over $\mathbb{P}^n$ in such manner, i.e. I need an embedding of $Tot(\mathcal{O}(1))$ in simple variety and defining equations. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is the complement $\mathbb{P}^{n+1} - \{x\}$ of a point in a projective space.

Comment: Shouldn't $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}\setminus\{x\}\to \mathbb{P}^n$ be the tautological line bundle?

Comment: The tautological line bundle contains a divisor, isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^n$, with normal bundle of degree $-1$ (namely, the zero section). On the other hand every effective compact divisor in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}-\{x\}$ has a positive normal bundle. In particular, a hyperplane avoiding $x$ has normal bundle of degree $1$. The projection from the point identifies the complement of $x$ with the total space of this normal bundle.

Comment: Thank you, Tony. Maybe you know such simple description of $Tot(O(n))$ for $n>1$ also?

Comment: You can get $Tot(\mathcal{O}(n))$ in a similar manner by deleting a point from a weighted projective space. But this is more contrived. And is not really better than thinking of $Tot(\mathcal{O}(n))$ as a toric variety. So this probably is not what you want.

Comment: @TonyPantev would you mind saying which weighted projective space contains the total space of $\mathcal{O}(n)$ and how to think of it as a toric variety?

Comment: $Tot(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}(k))$ is $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}(1,1,\ldots,1,k) - \{x\}$, where $x = (0:0:\ldots:0:1)$.

Answer (score 14):

Dear Luther King, since you ask for equations, let me add them to Tony's beautifully geometric answer.

Consider $\mathbb P^{n+1}$ with homogeneous coordinates $(z_0:z_1:\ldots:z_{n+1})$ and $\mathbb P^{n}$  enbedded as the hyperplane $z_0=0$. If $x\in\mathbb P^{n+1}$ is the point $x=(1:0:\ldots:0)$, the required total space $T=Tot \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^{n}}(1)$   is the complement
$T=\mathbb P^{n+1} \setminus \{x\}$ of  $x$ in $\mathbb P^{n+1}$. The fiber of our bundle 
$\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^{n}}(1)$ at the arbitrary point $(0:z_1:\ldots:z_{n+1}) \in \mathbb P^n$ is the set of all $(\lambda:z_1:\ldots:z_{n+1})$ with $\lambda \in k$ (base field) .

The one-dimensional vector space structure on the fiber is given by $(\lambda:z_1:\ldots:z_{n+1})+(\mu:z_1:\ldots:z_{n+1})=(\lambda +\mu:z_1:\ldots:z_{n+1})$ and similarly for products by scalars.
Beware that we   definitely do not have an isomorphism from our fiber to $k$ defined by  $(\lambda:z_1:\ldots:z_{n+1})\mapsto \lambda$: this is not even a well-defined map. This is not surprising: after all $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^{n}}(1)$ is not a trivial bundle!

**A more canonical approach** (edited) Readers of the canonical faith may suppress coordinates as follows.

Consider a $k$ - vector space $V$ of dimension $n+1$, its projectivization
 $\mathbb P (V)$ and its embedding  $\mathbb P (V) \to \mathbb P (k \oplus V)$ sending the point $\mathbb P (l) \in \mathbb P (V) $  to the point 
 $\mathbb P (0\oplus l)  \in  \mathbb P (k \oplus V)$. The vector bundle $\mathcal O _{\mathbb P (V)} (1)$ then has as total space the open subset 
 $T\subset \mathbb P (k \oplus V)$ obtained by deleting $x=\mathbb P (k \oplus 0)$ from
 $\mathbb P (k \oplus V)$ i.e.
 $T= \mathbb P (k \oplus V)\setminus x$. The fiber over 
 $\mathbb P (l)$ [identified with $\mathbb P (0\oplus l)$] is 
 $\mathbb P (k \oplus l)\setminus x$, a vector space of dimension one with origin the point
  $\mathbb P (0 \oplus l)$ but with no prefered isomorphism to $k$.

**Elementary geometry** It may clarify the above to recall that given a one dimensional projective space $\mathbb P$ over $k$, if you delete a point  $x$ from it you get a one dimensional  affine space 
  $\mathbb P \setminus x$ and if you choose in it an origin, you  get a one dimensional vector space, but that vector space has no prefered isomorphism with the vector space $k$.

Answer (score 11):

For me the best description of $Tot(O(1))$ is the tautological --- as the relative spectrum of the sheaf of algebras $A = O \oplus O(-1) \oplus O(-2) \oplus \dots$ on $P^n$:
$$
Tot(O(1)) = Spec_{P^n}(A).
$$
This allows to work with $Tot(O(1))$ more effectively than any other description. For example, a coherent sheaf on $Tot(O(1))$ can be represented by a quasicoherent sheaf $F$ on $P^n$ together with a morphism $F(-1) \to F$ inducing on $F$ a structure of an $A$-module.

Comment: Yes, I know about such description, but for my purposes the above one is preferable. 